# jQuery/HTML Select: Show more text in selected option when select is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-select

Given the following drop down list:
[image: Drop down list]

I have two optgroups, though there will be more generally, when an option is selected what is shown in the closed select box is:
[image: Current selection]

Using jQuery, CSS or some other means, how can I have the closed select box show the following information?
[image: Desired selection]

Showing all that information in each option in the drop down is extremely ugly and unnecessary. I only need to show the extra information when the select is not open. The extra information will be needed as they may have forgotten which "Report 1" they selected.

Each HTML option set looks like the following:

```
<optgroup label="Chemistry: Alchemists - 2015/16">
    <option academic_year="2015/16" report_set_id="1234" report_name="Report 1" class_name="Alchemists" class_subject="Chemistry">Report 1</option>
    <!-- etc. -->
</optgroup>
```

I'm currently operating on the idea of rewriting the option on open and close of the select menu, but is there a better way as it's not quite working as desired? Maybe a jQuery plugin that I can't find or overlooked? I have tried the following jQuery with limited success:

```
$('.start-reporting select').unbind().change(function(){
    var $selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected'),
        details = {
            class_name: $selectedOption.attr('class_name'),
            class_subject:$selectedOption.attr('class_subject'),
            report_name:$selectedOption.attr('report_name'),
            report_set_ID:$selectedOption.attr('report_set_ID')
            academic_year:$selectedOption.attr('academic_year')
        };
    $selectedOption.val( $selectedOption.html() );
    $selectedOption.html( details.class_subject + ': ' + details.class_name + ' (' + details.report_name + ') - ' + details.academic_year );
    $( this ).blur();
});
$('.start-reporting select').click( function() {
    if( $( this ).is( ':focus' ) ) {
        var $selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
        $selectedOption.html( $selectedOption.val() );
    }
});
```

The problem with the current code I have tried is that if the user opens the drop down menu the option is reset to "Report 1" or whatever as required, but if they don't select a new option and just click out of the select then it closes without rewriting the option to include the extra necessary details. There is also a noticeable delay in rewriting the option after opening the select. No delay on rewriting after a change of option though.

Comment: Do you mean - after you select an option, another select box comes up?

Comment: @GavinThomas No, sorry if it's not clear, it's the same select box. What I mean is when the select box is closed, i.e. the user has selected an option, how can I have the option display that extra information? But only when the select is closed.

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).attr("report_name"));
    });

    var $opt = $(this).find("option:selected");
    $opt.text($opt.attr("class_subject") + ": " + $opt.attr("class_name") + "(" + $opt.attr("report_name") + ") - " + $opt.attr("academic_year"));
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vnq5tfdk/1/)

Comment: My apologies for the delay in accepting this as the answer. It was a very busy time of year. This wasn't quite exactly what I was looking for when I asked the question but after some testing and trying other options it ended up being better, so thanks!

Comment: @joe92 no problem! Thank you.